# Firebase and Angularfire nightmare migration for Update

Tags: firebase

I am new to firebase and I am having a bit of a nightmare trying to adapt old code to what is now deprecated and what is not. I am trying to write a function which updates one "single" record in my datasource using the now approved $save()promise but it is doing some really strange stuff to my data source.

My function (should) enables you to modify a single record then update the posts json array. However, instead of doing this, it deletes the whole datasource on the firebase server and it is lucky that I am only working with testdata at this point because everything would be gone.

```
$scope.update = function() {
  var fb = new Firebase("https://mysource.firebaseio.com/Articles/" + $scope.postToUpdate.$id);
  var article = $firebaseObject(ref);
  article.$save({
    Title: $scope.postToUpdate.Title,
    Body: $scope.postToUpdate.Body
  }).then(function(ref) {
      $('#editModal').modal('hide');
      console.log($scope.postToUpdate);
    }, function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

}

Funnily enough I then get a warning in the console "after" I click the button:

*Storing data using array indices in Firebase can result in unexpected behavior. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase for more information. Also note that you probably wanted $firebaseArray and not $firebaseObject.*

(No shit?) I am assuming here that $save() is not the right call, so what is the equivalent of $routeParams/$firebase $update()to do a simple binding of the modified data and my source? I have been spending hours on this and really don't know what is the right solution.

Comment: Migration guide? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/migration-guides.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's additional code that you've left out, your `article` $firebaseObject should most likely use the `fb` variable you created just before it.

```
var article = $firebaseObject(fb);
```

Additionally, the way in which you're using `$save()` is incorrect. You need to modify the properties on the $firebaseObject directly and then call `$save()` with no arguments. [See the docs for more.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-save)

```
article.Title = $scope.postToUpdate.Title;
article.Body = $scope.postToUpdate.Body;

article.$save().then(...
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting that. I forgot to amend it. The main problem is that the data in the firebase datasource gets deleted every time I trigger the $save(). Why is that? Am I not using the correct call?

Comment: `$save()` sounds appropriate for what you're trying to do. What data exactly is being deleted?

Comment: Hey this worked but I am still trying to understand it. There seems to be a lot of variable definition. Is it not possible to bind the article variable to my HTML elements? i.e. <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="postToUpdate.Title">

Comment: In response to your previous argument. When I did not explicitly associated article.Title with $scope.postToUpdate.Title as per your example the record was just being deleted for some reason.

Comment: [You can indeed bind the $firebaseObject to your view](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html#section-full-example), but you'd have to do it when the form is first displayed. You can also use three-way bindings if you want changes to be made in real-time.

Comment: BTW I meant "comment" not argument above but could not edit it :-) I am not sure I understand what they are doing in your link with the use of random. I thought I could just store the whole post array in my article variable and it would automatically assume that everything under $firebaseObject(fb) would be associated with it.